# Returning a "Using" var

Tags: c#, asp.net, memorystream

I need to return a MemoryStream, and currently I do it like this:

```
String ICallbackEventHandler.GetCallbackResult()
{

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        this._synth.Rate = this.Rate;
        this._synth.Volume = this.Volume;
        this._synth.SetOutputToWaveStream(stream);

        string sText = this.Context.Items["data"].ToString();
        this._synth.Speak(sText);

        //rewind to beginning of stream
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        using (var nMp3Stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var rdr = new WaveFileReader(stream))
        using (var wtr = new LameMP3FileWriter(nMp3Stream, rdr.WaveFormat, LAMEPreset.STANDARD))
        {
            rdr.CopyTo(wtr);
            nMp3Stream.Position = 0;

            return (String.Concat("data:audio/mpeg;base64,", Convert.ToBase64String(nMp3Stream.ToArray())));
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't think that's the proper way. I guess I shouldn't return a `using` variable, right?

If not, how could I do this?  I need to dispose the MemoryStream, I think.  When should I do this, or should I let the GC do this?

Comment: You *aren't* returning a variable in a `using` though...you're just returning a string.

Comment: "I need to return a MemoryStream", but then you proceed to return a string.

Comment: @Evk You're right. However, I thought that the MemoryStream was being locked by the ConvertToBase64String function.

Comment: What do you mean by `being locked`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess I shouldn't return a using variable, right?

You don't return "using var" at all. 
You convert content of it into the string , and return that string instead.

```
return (String.Concat("data:audio/mpeg;base64,", 
                   Convert.ToBase64String(nMp3Stream.ToArray())));
```

Here you create *a new* instance of a `string`, fill it with content of `MemoryStream` and return that instance.

> I need to dispose the MemoryStream, I think.

Yes, you have to think about lifetime of your instances.

> When should I do this, or should I let the GC do this?

In most scenarios it's *you* who have take care of it and you're doing it proper way, at least judging from the code sample provided.

But, a lot depends on your concrete application design and execution dynamics.
For example:

- consider performance implication of converting memory stream into the `string`
- consider that at the moment of conversion you allocate almost 2x memory: one  for `MemoryStream` another for `string`

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually returning the `using` variable in this code. The `ToArray()`  call created a new array object with memory separate from the `nMp3Stream` object. Additionally, `Convert.ToBase64String()` created a new string object separate from the array, and `String.Concat()` created yet another string separate from the first string.

So while I question the efficiency of this code, especially as it relates to address exhaustion via the Garbage Collector Large Object Heap, it's certainly not going to run into any problems with `using`.

If you're interested in fixing the performance issues, that's a much bigger question which is likely to involve changing how this method is used in the first place.

For the situations where you really do want to return the subject of a `using` block from a method, the pattern is typically to *remove* the using block, and instead move that block to the caller. In the case where the `using` subject needs a longer life span, perhaps as a class member, then the class should be written to implement `IDisposable`, so class instances can themselves be the subject of a `using` block.